# Python Debugger which supports Black Boxing?

Tags: python, debugging, ipdb

If I use the debugger, most of the times I just want to see what the interpreter does in my code. I want to step over all code of the framework and libraries I use.

AFAIK this is called *Black Boxing*.

How can I do this with Python ipdb or an other Python debugger?

Imagine this:

I use a orm framework which I trust, and don't want to debug.

```
cut_hair_method(orm_object.user)
```

The method `cut_hair_method()` is mine, and I want to debug it.

The `orm_object` is from the framework I use. The debugger will step into the orm-code and do some special things, which I don't care about. I have no way to tell the debugger: Don't jump into the orm code!

**Update**

For my case it would be very easy to decide which code should be in the black box and which code not: Code in `$VIRTUAL_ENV/src/` is not in the black box, all other code is. Except I explicitly tell the debugger something else.

**Update2**

I have the name "Black Boxing" from this article: https://hacks.mozilla.org/2013/08/new-features-of-firefox-developer-tools-episode-25/

Comment: Any good debugger will feature "step over" commands. Black-Boxing is far more than just debugging. Black-boxing is an idea centered around how to test (and not debug) applications.

Comment: I added an example. AFAIK "step over" is not possible everywhere.

Comment: Instead of using step-over if that isn't working for you - why not set a break point in the `cut_hair_method, and then run.... I seem to remember the IDLE IDE had a blacklist of modules not to step through, but i also seem to remember it didn't work too well (when i used it several years ago - i might be wrong though).

Comment: @TonySuffolk66  I know how to use a debugger with step-over step-into since about 20 years (first one was turbo pascal). I know how to set breakpoints, but it just does not feel like flying. It is cumbersome.

Comment: Just use `r` to return from the ORM call. It is really not that hard. `s` into `orm_object.user`, `r` step out again and straight into `cut_hair_method()`.

Comment: It's a valid question, without an easy answer. I too would like to configure simple, understandable heuristics to automatically `step into` vs `step over` depending on what current point is. Perhaps it by module, perhaps something else. Most debuggers are scriptable, attach a test to current frame after step and finish/return if you don't like it.

Comment: I opened a feature request for PyCharm: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-14789

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Python debugger base class ([bdb.Bdb](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/bdb.html#bdb.Bdb)) has an a .skip attribute, giving a list of module names to skip over. You can provide this list either when instantiation the debugger, or later. If you want to provide a negative list (list of module that are your own), or otherwise compute whether a module should be skipped, you can subclass the debugger class and override is_skipped_module.

Answer (score 0):

Since PyCharm version 4.5 there is a feature called "Step into my code": https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/whatsnew/#StepIntoCode

It works. I my case, I just want to step into my code (Django application), but not into the code of django itself. The default short-cut is complicated (alt-shift-F7) but it is easy to change it.

Related issue: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-14789